# How to give permission for an IAM service account to run a docker container within a GCP VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to run a docker image on startup of a Google Cloud VM. I have selected a fresh service account that I created as the Service Account under VM Instance Details through the console. For some reason the docker run command within the startup script is not working. I suspect this is because the service account is not authorized to run the "docker" command within the VM - which was installed via a yum install. Can anyone tell me how this can be done i.e. to give this service account the permission to run docker command?

Edit.
Inside the startup script I am running `docker login` command to login to Google Container Registry followed by a `docker run` to run an image.

Comment: What docker command are you running? Are you trying to pull an image? Depending on the docker command, it could be due to missing Cloud IAM roles or it could be related to something else.

Comment: In addition to what Jason said, look at the logfiles for the actual error message running docker.

Comment: I have updated the question with command details. Will check the log files as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution and want to share it here so it helps someone else looking to do the same thing. The user running the docker command (without sudo) needs to have the docker group. So I tried adding the service account as a user and gave it the docker group and that's it. `docker login` to gcr worked and so did `docker run`. So the problem is solved but this raises a couple of additional questions.

First, is this the correct way to do it? If it is not, then what is? If this is indeed the correct way, then perhaps a service account selected while creating a VM must be added as a user when it (the VM) is created. I can understand this leads to some complications such as what happens when the service account is changed. Does the old service account user gets deleted or should it be retained? But I think at least an option can be given to add the service account user to the VM - something like a checkbox in the console - so the end user can take a call. Hope someone from GCP reads this.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [article](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/), the steps you taken are the correct way to do it. Adding users to the "docker" group will allow the users to run docker commands as non root. If you create a new service account and would like to have that service account run docker commands within a VM instance, then you will have to add that service account to the docker group as well.

If you change the service account on a VM instance, then the old service account should still be able to run docker commands as long as the older service account is not removed from the docker group and has not been deleted from Cloud IAM; however, you will still need to add the new service account to the docker group to allow it to run docker commands as non root.

Update: automating the creation of a service account when at VM instance creation manually would be tedious. Within your startup script, you would have to first create the Service Account using the [gcloud commands](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account) and then add the appropriate [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource). Once that is done, you would have to still add the service account to the docker groupadd directory.

It would be much easier to create the service account from the [Console](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#iam-service-accounts-create-console) when the VM instance is being created. Once the VM instance is created, you can add the service account to the docker groupadd directory.

If you would like to request for a new feature within GCE, you can submit a Public Issue Tracker by visiting this [site](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Thanks for confirming @Jason

Comment: if the approach in my answer is correct, does it make sense to automate creation of a service account userid in a VM (automatically) when a VM is created? Is it possible to provide this option for users in case they need it?

Comment: Updated my original answer.

Comment: Thank you again Jason. Will check the public issue tracker. To be clear again, what I meant to be automated is not creation of the service account (and IAM permission assignment). I meant to automate just the creation of the service account user within the VM. Thank you again